# Convertir en datetime columna dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Buenos días,

Mi script lee un `csv` con diversas columnas. En la función de pandas `read_csv`lee:

```
data = pd.read_csv(filepath, index_col='Target', parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True)
```

El `dataframe`tiene este aspecto:

```
Target        Observer          StartTime                 StopTime  
Target1       RT1               2019-09-01 20:47:50.02    2019-09-01 20:57:50.02
```

Pero los `dtypes`que me da son:

```
Observer        object
StartTime       object
Stoptime        object
```

Necesito sacar la duración de cada observación, y luego otras operaciones en las que necesito poder tratar las fechas (i.e: ver cuánto tarda en aparecer la siguiente observación o `lead(StartTime) - StopTime`).

No consigo pasar de ninguna manera `StartTime` y `StopTime` a `datetime` para operar mejor con ellas.

He probado `pd.to_datetime()`y otras funciones y no dan resultado.

¿Alguna idea?

¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Tu formato de fecha es un poco inusual y no lo reconoce. Por aclarar un poco, el formato supongo que es año-mes-dia hora-minutos-?. ¿Que es el tercer parámetro de la hora? Si son segundos deberian ser 00-59. ¿son milisegundos? Este último parámetro es el gran problema a la hora de pasarlo a una fecha válida. Saludos

Comment: @FJSevilla (Edito la pregunta primero que me faltó poner el punto, es 50.02) `R` lo reconoce perfectamente. El formato es `%D-%M-%D %h:%m:%s`. En `R` con utilizar `ymd_hms(StartTime)` me sale ya como fecha.

Comment: Vale, ahora si es una fecha válida. Ahora te respondo.

Comment: ¡Genial! Perdona que fue un despiste @FJSevilla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para solucionar tu problema basta con que le pases de forma explícita a las columnas que debe parsear mediante el argumento `date_parses` . El formato es perfectamente asumible por `numpy.datetime64`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('datos.csv', index_col='Target',
                   parse_dates=['StartTime','StopTime'])

data['Elapsed_time'] = data['StopTime'] - data['StartTime']

print(data.dtypes)
print(data)
```

El csv de entrada que he usado (inventando datos):

> Target,Observer,StartTime,StopTime
>   Target1,RT1,2019-09-01 20:47:50.02,2019-09-01 20:57:50.02
>   Target2,RT1,2020-10-15 03:20:10.21,2020-10-15 04:01:48.21
>   Target3,RT1,2019-03-14 17:47:13.37,2019-03-14 17:57:21.52
>   Target4,RT1,2019-12-27 13:15:35.03,2019-12-27 14:57:14.52

**Salida:**

> ```
> Observer                 object
> StartTime        datetime64[ns]
> StopTime         datetime64[ns]
> Elapsed_time    timedelta64[ns]
> dtype: object
>         Observer               StartTime                StopTime  \
> Target                                                             
> Target1      RT1 2019-09-01 20:47:50.020 2019-09-01 20:57:50.020   
> Target2      RT1 2020-10-15 03:20:10.210 2020-10-15 04:01:48.210   
> Target3      RT1 2019-03-14 17:47:13.370 2019-03-14 17:57:21.520   
> Target4      RT1 2019-12-27 13:15:35.030 2019-12-27 14:57:14.520   
>
>            Elapsed_time  
> Target                   
> Target1        00:10:00  
> Target2        00:41:38  
> Target3 00:10:08.150000  
> Target4 01:41:39.490000
> ```

He creado una nueva columna mostrando la diferencia de tiempo entre ambas columnas.

Comment: Ya entes probé eso y no me funciona. Yo pongo esto: `data = pd.read_csv(filepath, index_col='Target', parse_dates=['StartTime', 'StopTime'])` y me devuelve esto (el mismo error que me daba cuando probé yo eso): **ValueError: 'StartTime' is not in list**

Comment: @cluna **copia y pega el contenido tal cual de la cabezera de tu csv** a ver si encontramos el problema. Mira a ver si hay algún espacio o algo que hace que el nombre de las columnas no sea 'StartTime' y 'StopTime'. Me refiero a algo como `Target,Observer,StartTime ,StopTime `.

Comment: ¡Era un espacio! ¡Gracias!

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo pasar ahora ese `datetime64`a `int64`? Lo intento con `total_seconds()`y no.. (te escribí por chat)