# Cambiar formato fecha ymd_hms a ymd

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un `dataframe`en `Python`con dos columnas: `StartTime` y `StopTime`. En una de las operaciones, necesito agrupar por día los datos (`StartTime`). Para ello necesito eliminar de esa columna las horas, minutos, segundos...

Los datos que actualmente tiene son de esta forma:

```
StartTime
2019-09-01 20:47:50
2019-09-01 22:47:50
2019-09-02 20:47:50
```

Y quiero que queden:

```
StartTime
2019-09-01
2019-09-01
2019-09-02
```

Para finalmente agrupar y contar el número de observaciones por día. En `R`es muy sencillo con `as_date()`y luego agrupando por `StartTime`y añadiendo una columna con `n()`.

No encuentro la forma de hacerlo con `Python`y `pandas`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No necesita eliminar para nada las horas si no quieres, basta con agrupar por fecha. Basándome en el DataFrame de tu [pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/80370/convertir-en-datetime-columna-dataframe) he creado el siguiente ejemplo:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd


datos =datos = StringIO('''\
Target  Observer                 StartTime                  StopTime                                                         
Target1      RT1   2019-09-01 20:47:50.020   2019-09-01 20:57:50.020
Target1      RT1   2019-09-01 20:47:50.020   2019-09-01 20:57:50.020
Target1      RT1   2019-09-01 20:47:50.020   2019-09-01 20:57:50.020
Target1      RT2   2019-09-01 20:47:50.020   2019-09-01 20:57:50.020
Target1      RT2   2019-09-01 20:47:50.020   2019-09-01 20:57:50.020
Target1      RT1   2019-09-02 03:20:10.210   2020-10-15 04:01:48.210
Target1      RT1   2019-09-02 03:20:10.210   2020-10-15 04:01:48.210
Target1      RT2   2019-09-02 03:20:10.210   2020-10-15 04:01:48.210
Target1      RT2   2019-09-02 17:47:13.370   2019-03-14 17:57:21.520
Target1      RT2   2019-09-02 13:15:35.030   2019-12-27 14:57:14.520
''')

df = pd.read_table(datos, sep='\s\s+',engine='python' ,parse_dates=['StartTime','StopTime'])
```

Lo que quieres es agrupar por observador y por fecha de inicio contando el número de observaciones por observador y dia. Podemos valernos de `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` para agrupar por observador y día y usar el método `agg` para crear una nueva columna con el recuento. El resultado es una nueva columna con el número de observaciones que existen por cada observador en un dia:

```
res = df.set_index('StartTime').groupby(['Observer', pd.TimeGrouper('D')]).agg({'Observer': 'count'}).rename(columns={'Observer':'Obs'})
```

**Salida:**

```
>>> res
```

> ```
>                         Obs
> Observer StartTime         
> RT1      2019-09-01       3
>          2019-09-02       2
> RT2      2019-09-01       2
>          2019-09-02       3
> ```

Comment: ¡Hola de nuevo @FJSevilla! Lo que yo quiero es contar cuántas observaciones hay por día. Sería sumar las StartTime por día (si aparecen tres el 1 de septiembre, luego tendría una columna con

Comment: StartTime          Obs
2019-09-01       3

Comment: @cluna si queres añadir una columna que te cuente los grupos basta con hacer algo como `res = df.set_index('StarTime').groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D')).agg(['sum', 'count'])`.No obstante, si estas trabajando con el df de tu pregunta anterior (columnas 'Target', 'Observer', 'StartTime', 'StopTime') debes especificar que hacer con las otras columnas al agrupar por dia. Deberias aportar un ejemplo real que se pueda reproducir junto a la salida esperada para ver más fácilmente lo que quieres.Me refiero por ejemplo, a como agrupas una observación con distinto observador o target pero mismo dia.Saludos.

Comment: Target es el mismo en todo el csv (en este caso). La idea es agrupar primero por Observer (eso ya está), y después por StartTime para contar las observaciones diarias por observer.

Comment: @cluna ¿Entonces lo que tienes ahora mismo es un Dataframe distinto  por cada observador con solo la columna StarTime de sus observaciones?

Comment: No, uno agrupado por Observer.

Comment: @cluna puedes agrupar por los dos campos a la vez que es lo mismo que agrupar primero por uno y luego por otro

Comment: @cluna tal y como dice Dans Merino puedes agrupar en una sola vez. He editado la respuesta (mira al final) creando un ejemplo basandome en tu anterior pregunta. Mira a ver si es esto lo que quieres. La salida es un multiindex pero se puede reindexar de forma simple si no lo queres así. Saludos.

Comment: Eso ya lo tengo agrupado con `data.groupby(['Observer', 'StartTime'])` Pero tampoco me da el resultado que quiero :/ lo que quiero es que si tengo varias observaciones en un día, se me agrupen todas por día. Así pueda hacer un ' n()' (en `R`, en `python`aún tengo que ver cómo)

Comment: @cluna si has mirado la edición (al final de la respuesta) lo que hace mi código es contar el número de observaciones por día precisamente. RT1 hizo 3 observaciones el dia 1 y 2 el dia 2. Rt2 hizo dos observaciones el dia 1 y 3 el dia 2. No llego a entender lo que quieres, como te comenté antes sería mejor que pusieras un ejemplo real con la salida esperada. Puedes usar mi ejemplo para construir la salida esperada sobre el si quieres. Saludos.

Comment: Perfecto en la edición. Gracias de nuevo, @FJSevilla

Comment: Otra cosa, ahora cuando hago un: `data['Obs'].mean()` me sale el conjunto y no por `Observer` como yo quiero.

Comment: @cluna si quieres la media por observador (aplicado al dataframe que acabamos de crear) debes usar `groupby` de nuevo: `media = data.groupby('Observer')['Obs'].mean()`

Comment: Perfect, lo resolví antes pero gracias :) Una última duda, (para no abrir otra pregunta). ¿Cómo hago en python esta operación en R `data<- mutate(data, revisit = lead(StartTime) - StopTime)`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60907/discussion-between-cluna-and-fjsevilla).

Answer (score 2):

Existen dos maneras de realizar la conversion y eliminar la parte del "tiempo" de la columna.

Por un lado el existe el método `dt.normalize` y por otro el atributo `dt.date` como ves ambos pertenecen al atributo `dt` de la serie.

Un ejemplo de utlización con tus labels

```
df["StartTime"] = df["StartTime"].dt.normalize()
```

o

```
df["StartTime"] = df["StartTime"].dt.date
```

La diferencia entre ambas posibilidades es que `normalize` te mantiene el tipo `datetime64` que pandas utiliza internamente lo que te permite seguir aprovechandote de todas las utilidades que ya vienen con pandas, mientras que `date` devuelve un objeto `datetime` de python.

Para agrupar por la fecha puedes hacer:

```
gb = df.groupby([df["StartTime"].dt.normalize(), df["EndTime"].dt.normalize()])
```